# why is this sed command failing to get the desired output

Tags: sed

testfile:

```
872iirji -- RANDOM STUFF -- skjkfj45j
GET /_ajax_htmlview?action=28&__and_so_on HTTP/1.1.
Host: my.website.com.
connection: blah blah blah
skjfkjfj
```

desired output:

```
_ajax_htmlview?action=28&__and_so_on
my.website.com
```

which I will join using sed backreferences to make it `http://my.website.com/_ajax_htmlview?action=28&__and_so_on`

```
sed -n 's=GET \/\(_ajax_htmlview[^ ]*\).*=\1=
        h
        /^Host/{
        s=.*:[ \t]*\(.*\).=\1=
        H
        x
        p
}'
```

but I get this:

```
Host: my.website.com
my.website.com
```

**EDIT** :  if I add `/^GET/{ }` as below then it seems to work, but how does this works and the previous one does not

```
sed -n '/^GET/{
        s=GET \/\(_ajax_htmlview[^ ]*\).*=\1=
        h
        }
        /^Host/{
        s=.*:[ \t]*\(.*\).=\1=
        H
        x
        p
}' testfile
```

Comment: Not an answer to why your `sed` doesn't work, but you could just do `perl -lne 'print "$1" if /GET \/(.+?)\s+/ || /Host:\s+(.*)/' file` or, if you have GNU grep:  `grep -oP '(GET /\K(.+?)\s+)|(Host:\s+\K.*)' file`

Comment: You are **unconditionally** overwriting the pattern space with `h` that is you're doing it **on each line**  so `Host: my.website.com.` is the last thing that gets written to the hold buffer before you do the `{s...;H;x;p}` part hence the result.

Comment: @don_crissti oops, you are right

Comment: sorry, I meant _"unconditionally overwriting the hold buffer with `h`"_...

Comment: More short `sed '/GET /h;/Host: /!d;s///;G;s/\n.* \(.*\) .*/\1/'`

Answer (score 0):

Well just for fun, obligatory awk solution ....

I worked out this bash oneliner that works too

```
buildit(){ Req=$(grep -oP '(?<=GET \/).*(?=HTTP)' $1); url=$(awk -F":" '/Host/{gsub(/ /, "",$2); print $2}' $1); echo "http://"$url"/"$Req; }
```

This creates a bash function in your shell that you can then call like this

```
$ buildit testfile
http://my.website.com/_ajax_htmlview?action=28&__and_so_on
```

There is a caveat though- this will only work if there is only a single instance of "Host" and "GET" in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Easier with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/GET.*ajax/ { print $(NF-1); getline; print $NF }' testfile
/_ajax_htmlview?action=28&__and_so_on
my.website.com.
```

The `awk` code looks for any GET request lines that also contains the string `ajax`, it then outputs the second to last field of that line and reads the next line.  From that next line, it outputs the second field.